# A seemingly difficult task at the beginning (while you've not started it yet)

Tags: idioms, expressions

How do you call a simingly quite difficult task (not necessarily mental or physical one) which requires lots of efforts and looks too difficult "at the beginning"?

The term / expression / idiom which I'm looking for often is sarcastically said to someone who finds a task unpreformable and far away from their capabilities and the realm of their abilities which is normally used in order to undermine their belief about the situation!

The only founded expression based on my researches is **daunting task**! Please consider the following self-made example:

> **A)** Hey dude! What's up? 
>   **B)** Nothing! Just I'm fed up with all these  unnecesaary math subjects! Tomorrow, I'll have an exame and I've not even cracked the book open! 
>  
>   **A)** No worries bro! **That's not a daunting task**. You'll pass it.

Now, I need to know:

> - **First)** If this sentence works here.
> - **Second)** If works, then whether it seems to be natural and idiomatic here.
> - **Third)** Whether there are some other alternatives in common use for this concept.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. The sentence works, as in it's valid English and it makes sense.
2. However, I've only ever heard the phrase "daunting task" used when something is seriously challenging. Examples:

> To send a rocket to the moon is a daunting task.
>
> Harvesting all these crops by nightfall is going to be a daunting task.

"Daunting" isn't used very often in conversation.

3. I would say:

> No worries bro! **It'll be a piece of cake!**

If a task is called a *piece of cake*, that means it is easy to accomplish.

> After taking calculus in high school, college algebra was a piece of cake!

This phrase can also be said lightheartedly/sarcastically about something that is actually difficult to perform.

> Run a marathon?! I never have before, but I'm sure it'll be a piece of cake.

---

More reading: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/piece%20of%20cake